# How to make viewpager wrap it's height to every child item

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview

Please how do I make my viewpager wrap it's Height to it's child item. I mean every child item within it, not the highest child. I want it to wrap to every child that is currently in focus. Plz I need help, hope its understandable.

so i created a custom class to extend viewpager.

```
public class wrapitemviewpager extends ViewPager {
List<Integer> childheight = new ArrayList<>(getChildCount());
int currposition = 0;

public wrapitemviewpager(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    onpagelistener();
    getLayoutParams();
}

public wrapitemviewpager(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet 
attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    onpagelistener();
    getLayoutParams();
}


@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    if (mode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED || mode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int height = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, 
MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

            int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
                height = h;

            childheight.add(i, h);
        }

        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, 
MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    requestLayout();
}

private void onpagelistener(){
    this.addOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currposition = position;
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
wrapitemviewpager.this.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = childheight.get(position);
            wrapitemviewpager.this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            wrapitemviewpager.this.invalidate();
        }

    });
}

}
```

and this is the layout

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/postimageorvideoviewlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.ntrii.Ovallook.customclass.wrapitemviewpager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:overScrollMode="never">

                </com.ntrii.Ovallook.customclass.wrapitemviewpager>



                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/pinnedshow"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="7.5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/broadcastpinnedshowimage"
                            android:layout_width="15dp"
                            android:layout_height="15dp"

android:src="@mipmap/fb20160712_13_31_09_saved_picture" />
                        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/pinnedtexttalk"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingStart="5dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:paddingTop="2dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                            android:text="BC Pinned"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorblack"
                            android:textSize="13sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the code you have tried and also the layout design you want.

Comment: just did. please a little help if u can. tanx in advance